# How to only return newest result in query from 3 joined tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, inner-join

I have 3 tables named Contracts, Bills, and Companies which I have inner joined on a value named "ContractID" which links all 3 tables. I have that query working well, however I would like only the newest result to be pulled. The ContractID field can return multiple results from the Contract table with different dates so DISTINCT isn't working to narrow it down.

The current query is as follows:

```
SELECT cn.ContractID
    , cn.Vendor
    , cn.ContractDate
    , b.ContractID
    , b.TotalBill
    , b.CurrentDue
    , cm.ContractID
    , cm.CompanyID
    , cm.[Description]
FROM [Contract] cn
INNER JOIN Company cm
    ON cn.ContractID = cm.ContractID
INNER JOIN Bill b
    ON cn.ContractID = b.ContractID
```

I am using MSSQLServer 2005. Can someone help me adjust the query so it only returns the newest ContractDate result for each ContractID?

Comment: You mean something like `ORDER BY Contract.ContractDate DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Edited question to use aliases and better formatting.

Answer (score 4):

If your query is ordered the way you want it you can simply add select Top 1 to your query and this will give you the first row:

```
SELECT Top 1 cn.ContractID , cn.Vendor , cn.ContractDate , b.ContractID 
     , b.TotalBill, b.CurrentDue, cm.ContractID, cm.CompanyID, cm.[Description] 
  FROM [Contract] cn 
 INNER JOIN Company cm ON cn.ContractID = cm.ContractID 
 INNER JOIN Bill b ON cn.ContractID = b.ContractID 
 order by cn.ContractDate DESC
```

Comment: SELECT Top 1 cn.ContractID
    , cn.Vendor
    , cn.ContractDate
    , b.ContractID
    , b.TotalBill
    , b.CurrentDue
    , cm.ContractID
    , cm.CompanyID
    , cm.[Description]
FROM [Contract] cn
INNER JOIN Company cm
    ON cn.ContractID = cm.ContractID
INNER JOIN Bill b
    ON cn.ContractID = b.ContractID order by cn.ContractDate DESC

Comment: You can _edit_ your question; there's no need to post extras in comments.

Comment: Joe, unfortunately I don't only want to return one contract, i want the newest row from each contract.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RANK() OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to give each ContractID a rank, then select only those with rank 1.  Ex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT      
        Contract.ContractID, 
        Contract.Vendor, 
        Contract.ContractDate, 
        Bill.ContractID, 
        Bill.TotalBill,
        Bill.CurrentDue, 
        Company.ContractID, 
        Company.CompanyID, 
        Company.Description,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ContractDate DESC) as RecordRank
    FROM Contract
    INNER JOIN Company 
        ON Contract.ContractID = Bill.ContractID
    INNER JOIN Bill 
        on Company.ContractID = Bill.ContractID
) qry
WHERE RecordRank = 1
```